# React Native animations in separate file

Tags: animation, reactjs, react-native

Animations using `Animated` with React Native can get pretty large and take up a lot of space, especially if you have several of them. Is there a way to have them in a separate file and if so how would they be called?

```
Animated.sequence([
  Animated.timing(this.state.move,{
    toValue: {x: 50, y: 100},
    duration:400
  }),
  Animated.timing(this.state.move,{
    toValue: {x: 0, y: 0,
    duration:400,delay:400
}),
]).start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out how to do it. Create a separate file like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
} from 'react-native';

var Anims = {
firstAnim(move) {
Animated.sequence([
  Animated.timing(move,{
    toValue: {x: 50, y: 100},
    duration:400
  }),
  Animated.timing(move,{
    toValue: {x: 0, y: 0,
    duration:400,delay:400
  }),
  ]).start()
  }
}

module.exports = Anims;
```

Then require it like this:

```
const Animations=require('./animations.js');
```

And call it like this:

```
Animations.firstAnim(this.state.move);
```